# AngularJS Checkbox

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I came across the AngularJS Material website and was playing around with some tutorials. The last example about checkboxes confused me a bit [(this tutorial site)](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox)

```
<div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="50" layout="column">
  <div >
    <fieldset class="standard">
      <legend>Using &lt;input type="checkbox"&gt;</legend>
      <div layout="row" layout-wrap flex>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="standard" flex="50">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item, selected)"
                   ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"/>
            {{ item }}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering if it is possible to name checkboxes in html different, like (A,B,C,..) , but still work with the number (1,2,3,..) in the controller?

```
angular.module('checkboxDemo2', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
  $scope.selected = [];

  $scope.toggle = function (item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
      list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
      list.push(item);
    }
  };

  $scope.exists = function (item, list) {
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array having only numbers, so ng-repeat showing that numbers

if you want A,B,C.., then your array should be like

```
$scope.items = [{name:'A',value:1},[{name:'B',value:2},[{name:'C',value:3},[{name:'D',value:4}];
```

and your html check box could be

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="exists(item, selected)"
                   ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"/>
            {{ item.name }}
```

Comment: this works for me:
I just would like to add, that I changed something in syntax: $scope.items = [{name:'A',value:1},{name:'B',value:2},{name:'C',value:3},{name:'D',value:4}];

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a function in your controller to get the letter corresponding to the item (**A** corresponding to **1**, **B** to **2** and so on) like this :

```
$scope.intToChar = function(int){
    return String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + int - 1)
}
```

And in your ng-repeat, instead of displaying `{{item}}` you just need to display `{{intToChar(item)}}`

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rmc4RmaeJ45JPTPaS3NP?p=preview) is a working plunker

Answer (score 0):

you can add the character dynamically using `String.fromCharCode`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];

 $scope.fullArr = $scope.items.map(o=>{
     return {
        name : String.fromCharCode(64+o),
        num : o
     }
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in fullArr" class="standard" flex="50">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{item.name}}" ng-checked="exists(item, selected)"
                   ng-click="toggle(item, selected)"/>
            {{ item.num }}
          </label>
        </div>
</div>
```